# Will .abort() theoretically abort my javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have a question regarding javascript functions and the code `abort()`. I was wondering if `abort()` will theoretically abort my function. Here is the code:

```
    var somfunc = function somFunction() {
            //Does something...
    };

    somfunc.abort();
```

I wondering if the code above will theoretically work? Is it possible that `abort()` will abort my javascript function? As if it would work it be a good use when having ajax calls within javascript functions.

Comment: There is no `.abort` function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype

Comment: What do you mean by "*abort a function"*? What do you think would/could/should happen?

Comment: Browser JavaScript runs in sync so once you start running the function it will run until it stops it doesn't run anything else until it's done with the current process. The timeout function sets a time limit on the function but you can't stop it using some external command because it runs in sync

Answer (score 0):

`.abort()` is used to abort `XMLHttpRequest` instances normally. A `new` instance is an Object. Your use is improper, so **NO** it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

`somefunc` is only a reference to your somFunction, so theoretically there is nothing to `abort` and `somefunc.abort()` will throw a `TypeError`.

If you want a function that you want to abort in the future based on some future condition, you can set it in a timeout.

```
var timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
    someFunc(); // this will exec after 2000ms
}, 2000);

// execute some more code

// conclude you want to avoid executing someFunc, then clear the timeout

clearTimeout(timeoutId);
```